# Speeding up the felm command in R (lfe library)

Tags: r, performance, regression, linear-regression, panel-data

I am using the `felm` from the `lfe` library, and am running into serious speed issues when using a large data set. By large I mean 100 million rows. My data consists of one dependent variable and five categorical variables (factors). I am running regressions with no covariates, only factors.

The `felm` algorithm does not converge. And I also tried some of the tricks used in [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/vignettes/speed.pdf) short article, but it did not improve. My code is as follows:

```
library(lfe)
my_data=read.csv("path_to//data.csv")
attach(data.frame(my_data))

lev1 = unique(my_data$fac1)
my_data$fac1 <- factor(my_data$fac1, levels = lev1)
lev2 = unique(my_data$fac2)
my_data$fac2 <- factor(my_data$fac2, levels = lev2)
lev3 = unique(my_data$fac3)
my_data$fac3 <- factor(my_data$fac3, levels = lev3)
```

and now I run the regression, without covariates (because I'm only interested in the residuals), and with interactions as follows:

```
est <- felm(y ~ 0|fac1:fac2+fac1:fac3, my_data)
```

This line takes forever and does not converge. Note the dimension of the are as follows:

- `fac1` has about 6000 unique values
- `fac2` has about 100 unique values
- `fac3` has about 10 unique values

(and remember there are 100 million rows). I suspect there must be something wrong with how I use the factors, because I imagine that `R` should be able to handle such sizes (stata's [reghdfe](http://scorreia.com/software/reghdfe/) command handles it without problems). Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think that since you are using `unique()` , this will significantly reduce the numbers in your data set. Why don't you read your data/convert as a data.frame & make sure your data is numeric instead of factors